# Problem with input.value & addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, addeventlistener

I do an HTML input with a simple button. My goal is to take the value of the input with id "esercizio08" and print it if W click.

```
    <input id="esercizio08" name="test" type="text" value=""></input>
    <input type="button" value="..." id="button08"></input>
________

    let bottone = document.getElementById("button08");

    bottone.addEventListener("Click", controllo);

function controllo(){
            let valore = document.getElementById("esercizio08").value;
            return console.log(valore);
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty fine. Problem is that listener is named `click` not `Click` (small 'c').

```js
const bottone = document.getElementById("button08");
bottone.addEventListener("click", controllo);

function controllo(){
   let valore = document.getElementById("esercizio08").value;
   console.log(valore);
};
```

```html
<input id="esercizio08" name="test" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="..." id="button08"/>
```

Just for information: I've also removed `return` before `console.log()` because it is not needed and I've modified `<input></input>` to be single tag `<input/>`.